# How can I convert polygon features stored in Shapefile, GeoJSON or GML (over WFS) into obj file

Tags: shapefile, geojson, wfs, mapbox

I am currently working on an augmented reality application using ARKit. The required file formats are DAE or OBJ. My clients would like to display information stored within Shapefiles, GeoJSON or GML file formats. After much research I can't seem to find a simple solution on how to convert the polygons into the desired file formats. The best solution would be access to a free web-service that can complete the conversion for me. Mapbox provides some functionality with these files, however I am unaware if it can export to OBJ. Can anyone direct me to an existing solution (web-service) or a set of steps in order to complete the conversion?

Comment: Blender supports shapefile and OBJ  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export.html

Comment: Unfortunately I require a web-based solution. I have looked into Blender, but it doesn't meet my use case